# What is meant by "joint likelihood function" in this context?

Tags: likelihood, joint-distribution

I have two Binomial distributed random variables.

$$X_1\sim\text{Bi}\left(50,\theta_1\right)$$
$$X_2\sim\text{Bi}\left(50,\theta_2\right)$$

I sample from each distribution.

$$X_1=x_1=15$$
$$X_2=x_2=26$$

## Question

> formulate the **joint likelihood function** using the given information

I am curious to know what a joint likelihood function is?

## Attempt 1

In this attempt I calculated the likelihood for each observation separately and multiplied them together. I am curious to know if I am on the right track?

> First likelihood
> $$L\left(X_1=x_1|\theta_1,n\right)= {n\choose x_1}\theta_{1}^{x_1}(1-\theta_1)^{n-x_1}
> $$
> $$n=50,x_1=15$$
> $$L\left(X_1=15|\theta_1,n\right)= {50\choose 15}\theta_{1}^{15}(1-\theta_1)^{50-15}
> $$
> $$L\left(X_1=15|\theta_1,n\right)= (2250829575120) \theta_{1}^{15}(1-\theta_1)^{35}
> $$

similarly, the second likelihood is:

$$L\left(X_2=26|\theta_2,n\right)= {50\choose 26}\theta_{2}^{26}(1-\theta_2)^{50-26}
$$

> Is the joint likelihood their product?
>
> $$L_{\text{joint}}=L\left(X_1=15|\theta_1,n\right)\times L\left(X_2=26|\theta_2,n\right)$$

#### Further context

This is from a question in a 2nd year undergraduate statistics course which I am struggling with.

> [image]

Comment: Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3573982/321264.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22joint+likelihood%22.